# Add multiple values in table's column against specific id

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Can someone tell how can add multiple values against one id?

e.g I want to add multiple phone numbers against one id.

How can I do this? Give scenario should create two table or one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Give Scenario should create two table or one?

Yes, you should create a separate table for this data, where multiple rows contain separate phone numbers. There would then be a foreign key on the `id` linking these rows back to the single row with a specific `id` in the first table.

```
create table T (
    ID char(8) not null,
    /* other columns */
    constraint PK_T PRIMARY KEY (ID)
)

create table PhoneNumbers (
    ID char(8) not null,
    PhoneType varchar(12) not null,
    Number varchar(15) not null,
    constraint PK_PhoneNumbers PRIMARY KEY (PhoneNumbers,PhoneType),
    constraint CK_PhoneNumber_Types CHECK (PhoneType in ('Home','Work','Mobile')),
    constraint FK_PhoneNUmbers_T FOREIGN KEY (ID) references T(ID)
)
```